# How do I uninstall Windows 8 and install Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, installation

I have a friend, who just got a new Toshiba Satellite C series with Windows 8. I tried to uninstall Windows 8 and install Windows 7 but was unable to do so.

I did everything I could:

1. Boot disk - would not load (error message Media -- Fail)
2. Boot USB - would not load (error message Media -- Fail)
3. Loading Windows 7 disk from system, fails with different errors

Does anybody know what I can do in order to install Windows 7?

Comment: Have you disabled secure boot?

Comment: In addition to what @gronostaj suggests, you also may just want to take it completely out of UEFI mode.

Comment: I have disabled secure boot, but it's the same.

Comment: Then do what @techie007 suggested, and disable UEFI. Revert back to "Legacy BIOS Mode" or enable the "CSM (Compatibility Support Module)" or any other similarly worded option.

Comment: Thanks I made it work, yes I had to disable UEFI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toshiba explained all steps in a KB article:

**Steps to Install Windows 7 on a Windows 8 Unit**

http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/kb0/TSB2B03EX0002R01.htm

> If a Windows 8 OS was preinstalled on a notebook, some steps are necessary to prepare the notebook for a downgrade to Windows 7 OS.

```
 1. Changes in the UEFI firmware
 2. Boot a Windows 7 recovery media
 3. Change manually the partition table
```

1. Boot unit and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to get into BIOS, go to "Security"
   tab and disable `Safe Boot`. Go to "Advanced" tab, select "System
   Configuration" then change boot mode from `UEFI` to `CSM`. Press F10 to save changes and exit.
2. Boot unit from recovery media (Press F12 on bootup to boot from USB or DVD media)
3. Press Shift+F10 to open cmd, run diskpart and run the commands from the picture

[image]